# Ulimit error while starting Riak

Tags: riak

I had installed **RiakDB** using this [document](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/debian-ubuntu/#Installing-From-Apt-Get).

After installation i tried to start the **Riak** using the following command. But its giving some error.

```
sudo riak start

###Error

!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!

riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

#### Note

```
os - 12.04 LTS ubuntu

riak - 1.4.6
```

I am new to riak.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this document](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Linux) for the necessary changes to `limits.conf` and other files to increase the open files limit for the `riak` user.

In order to determine why Riak hasn't started on your server, you'll have to investigate the contents of the various log files in `/var/log/riak`. I suspect you'll find a relevant error message in `console.log` or `erlang.log`. If you could post additional information to your original question, that could help me diagnose the issue.